# Mock User Agent

Tags: c#, browser, moq, httpcontext

I'm writing unit tests in which I need a fake HttpContext. I used the HttpSimulator from Phil Haack (http://haacked.com/archive/2007/06/19/unit-tests-web-code-without-a-web-server-using-httpsimulator.aspx).
But an function in the Sitecore api throws an exception on the following code:

```
request.Browser.Browser.IndexOf("IE", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1;
```

I debugged my code and the request.Browser.Browser is empty. I tried to fill the property with Moq but I get an exception. I also tried to add it as a header.

My code looks like this:

```
using (HttpSimulator simulator = new HttpSimulator("/", "localpath"))
{
    //NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection { { "User-Agent", "IE" } };
    //simulator.SimulateRequest(new Uri("http://www.foo.bar"), HttpVerb.GET, nvc);
    simulator.SimulateRequest();        

    var browserMock = new Mock<HttpBrowserCapabilities>();
    browserMock.SetupAllProperties();
    //browserMock.SetupProperty(b => b.Browser, "IE");
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser = browserMock.Object;
}
```

Does anyone know how i can mock this property?

Comment: http://hadihariri.com/2009/03/31/mocking-useragent-property-in-asp-net-mvc-with-moq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not be done, you will have to use the HttpContextBase e.d. classes in MVC. Turns out unit testing with web forms is messy(?)

Answer (score 4):

Actually this is possible - you can set the Browser property directly on the request:

```
httpSim.SimulateRequest(new Uri("http://www.test.com"));

HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser = new HttpBrowserCapabilities
                                                        {
                                                            Capabilities = new Dictionary<string,string>
                                                                {
                                                                    {"majorversion", "8"},
                                                                    {"browser", "IE"},
                                                                    {"isMobileDevice","false"}
                                                                }
                                                        };
```